# How can the OS use all cores for my application?

Tags: multicore

I have a COM written in Delphi 101 Berlin. And I write a script to call its API (just one API, single-threaded, and each takes around 1 minute to finish).

I run the vbs file using cscript.exe (64 bit) (and I use the [simple job runner here](https://helloacm.com/the-simple-and-powerful-parallel-runner-for-windows-scripting-hosts/)), many copies (so there are many processes), at the same time.

However, I have tested on many PC (Windows 10 Pro), and it is observed that only roughly 1 core is running despite that it many have many cores.

For example, on my 2 CPUs ([HPZ800 Intel Xeon X5650](https://helloacm.com/review-hpz800-server-workstation-hp-z800-workstation-desktop-pc-tower-computer-powerhouse-2x-intel-xeon-x5650-48gb-ddr3-memory-2tb-hdd-1gb-nvidia-quadro/), 6 cores each = 12 cores), only 1 core is being used.

If some scripts exit early, then the rest CPU usage will be improved, but all together sum no more than 1 core.

My question, is how to write code in order to benefit from multi cores?

[image]

Comment: You say "I run the VBS file using cscript.exe...many copies (so there are many processes)". Do you have any proof that there are many processes being forked/spawned by cscript.exe? Seems pretty clear to me that your project is running as a single-threaded process.

Comment: as you can see in the screen shot,   there are many copies of cscript.exe (processes),  on my application,  it is single threaded.

Comment: Also, just because there are many processes running, this does not mean you will max out your CPUs. It depends on the nature of the process. If each process just does a sleep() for 60 seconds, you could have thousands of them without troubling your CPU at all.

Comment: Looking at [this article](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/16720/enable-multiple-cores-on-windows-7/) it seems that you have to enable multicores. Have you already done this or something like it? You might also take a look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/715129/how-can-i-tweak-windows-7-or-8-to-utilize-multi-core-processors) on superuser.

Comment: @PrestonHager  yes, it is already enabled. The article you provide is mainly to teach you how to disable some cores.

Comment: I would also point out that your processes might be fighting over some limited resource -- like a slow internet connection or something. The performance of a process can be bound by disk or network limitations, remote server sluggishness, connection timeouts, et. al.

Comment: @S.Imp  I see.   but my process is just doing some basic calculations, and filling in a big array..

Comment: I also found [an article](https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1247566-windows-10-use-only-first-cpu-core/) with this same problem. From what I gathered from reading it, it seems it's a bug that Microsoft needs to fix. Although there might be something I missed. Sorry if I'm not much help.

Comment: @SteakOverCooked the devil is in the details. Sounds like you've written a COM, and then are trying to invoke it many times simultaneously, yes? What does the COM do? Does it do any file access? Does it have to wait for some remote file fetch? Your COM might have some limitation where the distinct processes calling it are fighting over something -- you have to be careful when multithreading/multiprocessing.

Comment: Do the processes have a custom affinity?

Comment: @S.Imp  yes, there are some file accesses, but the file is open ShareRead,  and after that, mainly some basic calculations. I am sure it is not the I/O contest because I let it print out after I/O finished

Comment: No.  I try to set them to HIGH, PRIORITY, which does not help

Comment: Seems like it might be helpful to try and rule out the COM. Could you write a trivial COM that just performs a calculation in a loop and NOTHING ELSE?  E.g., set a var to some random int and then calculate its sqrt 100 million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In order to use multiple cores at the same time, multiple threads are
> required. The inverse is not true!
>
> To really take advantage of a multi-core system, an application should
> split up the main processing into multiple threads as well. Its
> algorithms need to be parallelized.

Source:  https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/multi-core-and-multi-threading/

My COM API is single-threaded. Therefore, multiple processes does not let OS utilize all cores. As explained in the comments, if each process just does sleep for 60 seconds, there is no way to trouble all the cores.

I have also another API with fully multithreading, and it can utilize all cores even with 1 process.

Also, it is mentioned that if there is I/O contest or multiple processes fighting for same resources, the utilizations for cores will be affected.

**Update**  I make some experiments and it turns out that A single-threaded process can utilize at most a core, however launching multiple of them can utilize all cores which is really up to the OS to decide. Please see my experiments in details [When Can Windows Utilize All the Cores?](https://helloacm.com/multi-processes-experiments-when-can-windows-utilize-all-the-cores/)

Comment: I'd like to add that : you don't have the control over what thread runs on which process and when..
This is the responsibility of the operating system or to be more specific the  scheduler.
All you can do is that you set priorities on processes, so the scheduler gives it more space.

Comment: I have tried setting high priority to processes, but it seems it does not help much.